# Sort Alphanumeric Values with dash sign

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

I have defined a table named Inventory that consists of one `varchar(45)` field named `ItemNameCode`.  Here is the table and contains the following alphanumeric values.

[image]

Which we want to sort alphanumerically as:

```
MES40
PT14
PT14-403
PT14-646-649
PT14-646-649
PT15-3-11
PT15-12-42
PT15-12-572-575
PT16-164
PT16-227
PT16-62-71
PT16-136
PT16-137
```

I tried the bellow query but not getting exact order:

```
SELECT ItemNameCode
FROM Inventory
ORDER BY LEFT(ItemNameCode,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',ItemNameCode)-1)
```

Comment: Simply ordering by `ItemNameCode` should work...
Moreover, you should **add** 1 to your left statement, not subtract 1 : what you did returns _PT_ although (I guess) you expect _PT14_

Comment: @irimias No, neither will work. Assuming the example list order the OP provided is correct, it appears that the dashes separate distinct numbers. Just ordering by treats it as a single (longer) number. e.g. PT16-62-71 would be regarded as 166271 and come last, but the OP wants it to be seen as 71 OF 62 OF 16.

Comment: Simply ordering by ItemNameCode should working perfectly.

Comment: @M.I.M.F Still no, as I described, and AMtwo describes in the answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, simply sorting by `ItemNameCode` doesn't give you the desired sort. Using `ORDER BY ItemNameCode` would sort the PT15 values like this:

```
PT15-12-42
PT15-12-572-575
PT15-3-11
```

But, you expect them sorted like this:

```
PT15-3-11
PT15-12-42
PT15-12-572-575
```

Based on your expected results, I would describe the desired sort behavior as "The string is made up of segments separated by dashes. The first segment is alphanumeric, and each subsequent segment is numeric. Sorting should be done by the first segment, then by the second segment, then by the third segment, etc"

To accomplish this, you'll need to essentially break the `ItemNameCode` into separate calculated columns, and cast the numeric segments to integer before sorting.

This method of splitting the string apart into separate columns is pretty ugly, but works:

```
SELECT ItemNameCode, c1.seg1, c2.seg2, c3.seg3, c4.seg4
FROM dbo.AlphaNumeric x
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,1) = 0 THEN x.ItemNameCode
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,1,CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,1)-1) 
                    END AS seg1,
                    CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,1)+1 AS pos1) c1
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c1.pos1 = 1 THEN NULL
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c1.pos1) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c1.pos1,8000) 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c1.pos1,CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c1.pos1)-(c1.pos1)) 
                    END AS seg2,
                    CASE WHEN c1.pos1 = 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c1.pos1)+1 
                    END AS pos2) c2
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c2.pos2 = 1 THEN NULL
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c2.pos2) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c2.pos2,8000) 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c2.pos2,CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c2.pos2)-(c2.pos2)) 
                    END AS seg3,
                    CASE WHEN c2.pos2 = 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c2.pos2)+1 
                    END AS pos3) c3
OUTER APPLY (SELECT CASE WHEN c3.pos3 = 1 THEN NULL
                        WHEN CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c3.pos3) = 0 THEN SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c3.pos3,8000) 
                        ELSE SUBSTRING(x.ItemNameCode,c3.pos3,CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c3.pos3)-(c3.pos3)) 
                    END AS seg4,
                    CASE WHEN c3.pos3 = 1 THEN 1
                        ELSE CHARINDEX('-',x.ItemNameCode,c3.pos3)+1 
                    END AS pos4) c4
ORDER BY c1.seg1, CAST(c2.seg2 AS INT), CAST(c3.seg3 AS INT), CAST(c4.seg4 AS INT)
```

If the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, etc values are not strictly numeric, and you also needed alphanumeric sorting, you could try using this alternate `ORDER BY` clause on the same query:

```
ORDER BY c1.seg1, 
        RIGHT('00000' + COALESCE(c2.seg2,''),5),
        RIGHT('00000' + COALESCE(c3.seg3,''),5),
        RIGHT('00000' + COALESCE(c4.seg4,''),5)
```

Comment: your approach is correct... i cannot get the answer by using ORDER BY ItemName Code. once i tried your answer but i'm gettin an error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'B22' to data type int."

Comment: @M.I.M.F it sounds like you have non-numeric (ie, alphanumeric) values in more than just the first segment. Can you confirm that's the case with your data?

Comment: @M.I.M.F -- I updated my answer with an alternate ORDER BY, since it sounds like the cast-to-int option doesn't work with all your existing data

Comment: Anoter Issue In the order PT06-200, PT07-870-871 and PT09-655 order is correct but my ItemCode like this "PT7-870-871, PT9-655" order getting wrong.. you can see bellow order...  
PT16-495
PT16-246`
PT7-870-871
PT9-655

Comment: 1 to 9 number contain before 0 only order is correct. if not that ItemCode going to bottom of the order...

Comment: Depending on your requirements, you may need to follow the same pattern I used to further split your criteria.  It sounds like you actually do not want to sort the first segment as a single item, but rather to sort on .... the alpha part, then the numeric part?  Or Sort on the first 2 characters, then the rest of the first segment?

Comment: I tried order is same.. not getting the answer...